# Creating synthetic dataset similar to a specific dataset

Tags: python, pandas, synthetic

I have a data set and want to work with an external ML team however because of NDA,  I can not share the original or anonymized dataset with them.

Currently I'm using `make_classificatio` to create a synthetic data however this is a little time consuming to first understand the statistics of original dataset and then create a synthetic dataset similar to the original one. For dataset example you may consider Iris or other public datasets,

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

I'm wondering if you know any better way to imitate the original dataset?

Comment: difficult to help you if you cannot share the dataset to give an example, looks like we're stuck in a paradox :p

Comment: say Iris dataset (or any other public dataset) `iris = datasets.load_iris()`